# Python - DocxTemplate - Not Printing "&" in final document

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I am running a script that takes the names from a csv file and populates them into individual word documents from a template. I got that part. But here is where I need a bit of help.

Some cells in the csv file are two names, such as "Bobby & Sammy." When I go check the populated word document, it only has "Bobby Sammy." I know that the "&" is a special character, but I am not sure what I have to do for it to populate the word documents correctly.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Edit: Code

```
csvfn = "Addresses.csv"
df = pd.read_csv('Addresses.csv')


def mkw(n):
tpl = DocxTemplate('Envelope_Template.docx')
df_to_doct = df.to_dict()
x = df.to_dict(orient='records')
context = x
tpl.render(context[n])
tpl.save("%s.docx" %str(n))
wait = time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
~
print ("There will be ", df2, "files")
~
for i in range(0, df2):
    print("Making file: ",f"{i}," ,"..Please Wait...")
    mkw(i)
    
print("Done! - Now check your files")
```

~ Denotes new cell, I am using JupyterLab

File is a standard csv file

[Standard CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnpG0.png)

[Without "&" Prints fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJdLz.png)

[Empty space where "&" is supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHKmB.png)

Comment: You'll need to share the relevant bits of code that show how you actually populate the document. In a string, `&` is not really a special character, but perhaps it is in the specific way you're putting the text in.

Comment: Added code to the original question

Comment: Thanks, please correct the indentation - I'd guess the function body ends after `wait = ..` but I'd rather not have to guess. Can you also share a few relevant lines from `Addresses.csv`, in particular one that has an ampersand `&` in the data? Also, there's typos in your code `df_to_doct `?

Comment: This has to do with XML escaping, mentioned here: https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/issues/105

Comment: I added pictures in case that helps. Not sure how to fix the issue from that post